# XBox 360 Controller not recognized on Assassin's Creed II PC

Tags: controllers, assassins-creed-2

I recently got Assassin's Creed II during the Steam Holiday Sale. I had played Assassin's Creed with my wired XBox 360 Controller without a problem, and I was looking forward to using it for this game.

However, when I went to the options menu to select controls, the controller was not available in the menu. The only options there were Keyboard, Keyboard (alternate), Keyboard + Mouse (2 buttons), and Keyboard + Mouse (5 buttons). The controller is plugged in and turned on, and I am able to use it in other games such as HL2, Portal 2, Steam Big Picture, and Assassin's Creed I.

If anyone has any help, it would be much appreciated, I have no idea what is going on and why it won't find my controller.
Thanks

Comment: If you have any other controllers plugged in, unplug them. Dark Souls, for instance, will only accept the first controller and In my setup, the first controller always seems to be a footswitch system I use for music.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be that the drivers aren't properly installed.

You can find the drivers located [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows). Windows 7 should work for Windows 8/8.1, but I am not entirely sure about Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest repairing game files. Library>acii>properties>local files>verify integrity of local cache. Or installing xbox controller drivers again. The problem here seems too vague without seeing in person.